# In Excel, Is there a way to create a dropdown that would change the formatting only of the free-text cell?

Tags: excel, format, dropdown

I am creating a table where co-workers will need to enter project updates in a cell (only a few words) and I would like to create a color-coded system to quickly see the status. Red: issue, Green: on Strack, White: FYI only.
I'd like to have a dropdown option on the cells with Red/Green/White and once selected, the format only of the cell would change accordingly (not the content).
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered conditional formatting?

Comment: I have, but since it is a free-text cell, I can't find a way to create a rule for conditional formating that would work. Is there another method?

Comment: you would create the drop down in an adjacent cell then have three rule for the user used cell dependent on the value of the drop down cell.

Comment: So the logic would look like IF B2=Red, then Format A2 (Red Background Red Font) OR IF B2=Green, then Format A2 (Green Background Green Font) OR IF B2=White, then Format A2 (White Background Black Font)?

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks Scott for putting me on the right track with the logic. Then a bit of fiddling with the rules (new to me) and it works.